# Post Photo to Group by Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, photo, facebook-group

```
params['access_token'] = accessToken;
params['message'] = messageWillSend;
params['link'] = 'http://www.webdoanhnghiep.biz';
params['url'] = "imageURL";
params['name'] = 'Post To Group';
params['upload file'] = true;

FB.api('/302826253125607/photos', 'post', params, function(response) {
    ...
});
```

Error: #URL# is an internal url, but this is an external request.

I can post to user photo, page photo. But how can i post to group photo?

Comment: The docs do not mention any album or photos connection for groups in the API.

Comment: Usually, if we don't mention album. Facebook will create a album with app name.

Comment: I’m not talking about a specific album, but the album _connection_ a Graph object might or might not have. User and Page have those, according to docs, but Group does not. Trying to access `/somegroup/albums` via Graph API Explorer results in an exception saying, _“(#3) App must be on whitelist”_

Comment: Oh, Yes it is. I also encouter this "(#3) App must be on whitelist". That mean, we unable to post photo to group via APP?

Comment: Unless you get your app whitelisted for that feature, yes. (But don’t ask me how to do that, I don’t know.)

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I try it myself then share it here.